# Query on Awk Script

Tags: awk

```
780745,0,3,0,sto_un_os_fast,daily,lonrb08390,lonrs08841,1355250030,0000015139,1355265169
783333,0,1,,sto_un_os_fast,daily,lonrb08390,lonrs08842,1355336488,0000032370,0000000000
778143,0,3,0,sto_un_os_fast,daily,lonrb08390,lonrs08841,1355163652,0000003967,1355167619
784864,0,3,0,sto_un_os_fast,daily,lonrb07366,lonrs08842,1355351424,0000001475,1355352899
```

In the above file, I would like to print `lonrb...` & 3rd column after that.

Can someone please help me with this?

The problem I face with `awk '{print $6, $9}'` is that the columns change for `783333,0,1,,` lines.

Comment: You say that the 783333 line needs different treatment; can you please show the output you expect and explain why `awk -F, '{print $7, $10}'` does not do what you want?

Comment: -1 Even after reading the answers posted so far and you're thanking @JonathanLeffler for his response, I can't figure out what it was you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Umm - you should be able to do this by specifying "," as the field separator.

```
awk -F, '{print $7, $10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that it looks like columns 7 and 10, I'm not sure what the issue is:

```
awk -F, '{ print $7, $10 }'
```

In the `783333,0,1,,` line, there is an empty field after the `1` and before the `sto_un_os_fast`, but empty fields still count as a field.

```
lonrb08390 0000015139
lonrb08390 0000032370
lonrb08390 0000003967
lonrb07366 0000001475
```

If you want a comma separating the output fields, then you can either use `OFS=,` or simply use `printf` instead of `print`.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } { print $7, $10 }'
awk -F, '{ printf "%s,%s\n", $7, $10 }'
```

Both those produce the output:

```
lonrb08390,0000015139
lonrb08390,0000032370
lonrb08390,0000003967
lonrb07366,0000001475
```

Comment: awk -F, '{ print $7, $10 }' - this will give wrong values for the below lines 783333,0,1,,sto_un_os_fast,daily,lonrb08390,lonrs08842,1355336488,0000032370 which works with awk -F, '{ print $6, $9 }'. I would like to get similar columns for both these line

Comment: @user1899817: So you want the fields 'daily' and '1355336488' for the line starting '783333'?  What is the basis for making that decision?  `$1 == 783333 && $2 == 0 && $3 == 1 && $4 == ""`?